# Get-ADGroup - List two or more named groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to list two or more named AD groups with Get-ADGroup.

Lets say, we have three named groups:

```
Groupname1
Groupname2
Groupname3
```

I know how to list one AD group by name:

```
Get-ADGroup Groupname1
```

I know how to list all AD groups:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter *
```

But how do I list two or more named AD groups in a simple way ?

```
#Does not work
Get-ADGroup Groupname1, Groupname2, Groupname3

#Does not work    
Get-ADGroup 'Groupname2','Groupname2','Groupname3'

#Does not work    
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=local" -filter { name -like "Groupname1","Groupname2","Groupname3"}
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe in an array of group-names, use a foreach-loop (as @MilanPinter has shown) or create a filter that matches one of them. Ex:

```
'Groupname1','Groupname2','Groupname3' | Get-ADGroup

Get-ADGroup -Filter { name -eq 'Groupname1' -or name -eq 'Groupname2' -or name -eq 'Groupname3' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$group = "groupname1","groupname2"
foreach ($gp in $group) {get-ADGroup $gp}
```

Basically, you need to put your groupnames in an array, and the loop trough each one of them. [(Syntax for foreach)](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html).